# Exempt iframes from the main document's CSP sandbox

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, iframe, content-security-policy

Is it possible to exempt iframe's from their parents' CSP sandbox (when the parent has its CSP sandbox enabled using the `Content-Security-Policy` header)?

I have seen https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webappsec/2013Jan/0027.html, but it doesn't seem to be true. At least not any more.

I've tried, because nothing else comes to mind, overriding the parents' CSP header by serving the iframed document with a more liberal CSP header, but that didn't make any difference.

Is this behavior, where iframed documents inherit their parent's CSP, documented anywhere (i.e. by W3C)?

To give you some background here: the idea is to sandbox the main document, but allow for some custom privileges through a trusted unsandboxed iframe (the untrusted main page would use `postMessage` to tell the trusted iframe to do certain things on its behalf).

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible, but as google said in it's post referring to this topic "It's a trade-off though: sandboxed pages can't use the  APIs. If you need to do things like eval(), go this route to be exempt from CSP, but you won't be able to use the cool new stuff. and below is a sample of this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Woot</h1>
    <script>
      eval('console.log(\'I am an eval-ed inline script.\')');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```